# Weight painting: absolutely nothing happens when I click

Tags: weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

I'm following the donut tutorial by blender guru (https://youtu.be/4WAxMI1QJMQ?t=1226) and now I'm stuck on the weight painting. I'm quite sure that I followed the tutorial:

- added a new vertex group to the icing mesh (maybe this would not be needed if everything would just work?!)
- changed to weight paint mode
- the icing of the donut is blue
- but when I now click anywhere in the blue mesh nothing happens. No weights are painted

Interestingly when I choose the gradient tool I see weights painted - but no other tool in the weight painting mode seems to do anything. Isn't the left mouse button meant to do the painting? Do I need to use some other keys?

You can find the blend file here: https://tobiberlin.de/blender/Donut.blend - I already realized that the number of vertices are way too high (I think I supplied some more subdivision modifiers as needed) but as far as I understand this should not be the problem.

[image: Screenshot of my blender work space - maybe helpful?]

Comment: since you are a beginner it is a good idea to share your blend file so we can check it out

Comment: Thank you for youre response... I uploaded the file here: https://tobiberlin.de/blender/Donut.blend

Comment: if i open your file, i can weight paint immediately (click on donut and hold mouse button down while moving) - without changing anything [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dChi.png what Blender version r u using?

Comment: the current one... 3.3.1

Comment: i just tried 3.3 - worked too - downloading 3.31 now...needs 13 mins :( maybe you can try another version in the meantime?

Comment: just downloaded 3.31 - works too. So i can just recommend downloading blender again and maybe restart your computer

Comment: thank you very much for your support... I uninstalled and re-installed blender and now it works. I just needed to delete some local folders completely where scripts and addons were stored before installing again... Maybe there was a problem with an addon. Thank you a thousand times!!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me at least, it fixed itself when I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and applied all transforms.